# How to make a command which shows what servers the member is in (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I have tried many ways but it didn't worked so if any one has any idea about making the command pls share with me

here's my code

````
async def serverlist(ctx):
    mS = ', '.join([str(server) for server in member.guilds])
    s = len(mebmer.guilds)
    print("Server list: " + mS)
    if s < 10:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="This user is currently in this server" + str(mS) + " servers:", description="```json\n" + mS + "```", colour=0xFFFFF)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
````

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: my error is attribute error member object has no attribute guilds

Comment: Are you referencing `member.client` anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes .join([str(server) for server in member.guilds])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add `member` as a command argument:
`async def serverlist(ctx, member: discord.Member):`

You can get `guilds` list using the following code:

```py
guilds = [guild.name for guild in bot.guilds if guild.get_member(member.id) is not None]
```

Invoke a command by typing something like `[yourprefix]serverlist @Member#1234` in a chat.

```py
@bot.command()
async def serverlist(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    guilds = [guild.name for guild in bot.guilds if guild.get_member(member.id) is not None and guild != ctx.guild]
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"This user is currently in this server and in {len(guilds)} servers", description='\n'.join(guilds), color=0xFFFFF)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Note:** This only will display only guilds that have your bot and the specified member.

Comment: got an error  raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: Use `" ".join(guilds)` instead of `+ guilds`.

Comment: ill try it, one sec

Comment: im confused lol can u explain?

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: nope can u pls explain me with the full code?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer and added an example.

Comment: one sec ill try it

Comment: it shows the server where the member is in with the bot. I need like it should show the list of servers the user is in without the bot

Comment: @IXD22lathesh It's impossible.

Comment: lel ik i just asked if it is possible